# access nested array in addclick function with react

Tags: reactjs

I have a this const which contains some arrays and nested arrays:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState({
  'DevOps Project Admins': [""],
  'Landing Zone Environments': [{
    'Azure AD Groups for Access Control': [{
      "role": ""
    }]
  }]
}); // Result from submitted form
```

i am attempting to add a new item to the nested array `Azure AD Groups for Access Control` but i an not sure how to access it. When i press "add" and the function get activated it gives me a error:

```
e.Landing Zone Environments.Azure AD Groups for Access Control is not iterable
```

this is my add function:

```js
const handleaddclickinner = (i) => {
  const list = [...value['Landing Zone Environments']['Azure AD Groups for Access Control']];
  list[list.length] = {};
  setValue({ ...value,
    ['Landing Zone Environments']: { ...value,
      ['Azure AD Groups for Access Control']: list
    }
  });
}
```

and this is the whole html

```js
{
  value['Landing Zone Environments'].map((x, i) => {
      return (
          <div>
              <div>
                  <label >Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="Name" required={false} placeholder="Example: prod" onChange={e => handleinputchange(e, i)} />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <label >Advisor Email</label>
                  <input type="text" name="Advisor Email" placeholder="Example: advisor@invalid.xyz" onChange={e => handleinputchange(e, i)} />
              </div>
              <div>
                  <button class="minus_button" onClick={() => handleremove(i)}>-</button>
              </div>
              <div>
                  {
                      x['Azure AD Groups for Access Control'].map((y, j) => {
                          return (
                              <div>
                                  <label>AzureAD</label>
                                  <div>
                                      <label >Role</label>
                                      <input type="text" name="role" required={false} placeholder="Example: admin" onChange={e => handleinputchangeinner(e, i, j)} />
                                  </div>
                                  <div>
                                      <button class="minus_button" onClick={() => handleremoveinner(i, j)}>-</button>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          );
                      })}
                  <button class="array_button" onClick={() => handleaddclickinner(i)}>AzureAD</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      );
  })}
```

Comment: `Azure AD Groups for Access Control` is also inside array. So you will have to loop and get necessary object

Comment: Try `value['Landing Zone Environments'][0]['Azure AD Groups for Access Control'].push({})` instead

Comment: @Rajesh it does not update live when i do this - is it possible to make it do that?

Comment: @NadiaHansen You need to set it again to state. Just push will not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `hasOwnProperty` to find the object inside Landing Zone Envs which has Azure AD Groups for Access Control and push the new entry.

```js
const handleaddclickinner = (i) => {
  let _newValue = value;

  _newValue["Landing Zone Environments"].find(_obj => _obj.hasOwnProperty("Azure AD Groups for Access Control")).push({
    "New Entry": "New Entry Value"
  });

  setValue(_newValue);

}
```